# In what situation can I hold the ability key to use it asap after leaving the stun?

Tags: overwatch

I recently learned that holding the `wraith form` or `ice block` button while being hooked by a enemy Roadhog allows you to use the ability the very moment the hook stun wears off.

**Does this apply to every skill?** I.e. can every skill be hold to activate the moment the player gets back control of their character?

**Does this work with every type of stun?** There are multiple stun abilities in Overwatch (Reinhardts earthshatter, McCrees flashbang, Meis primary attack and blizzard ult, Anas sleep dart, Roadhogs hook (Both for the hooked and Roadhog himself)). Does each stun allow holding the ability key to use it asap?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Does this apply to every skill?

**Yes, but**

There are a couple of skills that require a target. A few that come to mind are Mercy's Guardian Angel, Ana's Nano Boost, and Zenyatta's Orbs of Harmony/Discord. You need to have a target acquired when the skill becomes available or else it won't activate.

> Does this work with every type of stun?

**Yes.**

Not only does it work with stuns and stun-like abilities, it works with the cooldown of the ability itself. If you really need to ice block but it's on cooldown, you can just hold the button for it and it will activate the instant it's ready.

Comment: I think if you are doing this technique on a cooldown ability you need to release the key between uses though.

For example you can't just hold down Phara's Concussive Blast all match and fire it as soon as it is ready, you need to let go after it's fired and hold down again to fire as soon as it is next available.